# Pandas how to get onclick values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, onclick

I'm looking forward to find-out the `column header sorted out` according to the values in each of the column, as in the below dataframe i have three columns `date` , `sleep` and `calories` So, if i want to click on the any of the columns they should be able to sort the values flipping the higher values first and the gradually smaller below.

Let's Suppose i have `date` column and if right now if I'll click on it its should flip the values and `2016-04-02` will get on top.

### Below is an example DF:

```
         date  sleep  calories
0  2016-04-01   11.2      2740
1  2016-04-02    7.3      3600
```

I want to save it as html form which may have the ability of sorting as i stated above, Will that be possible while preserving it into html like `df.to_html('file.html')`.

I have searched around it but didn't get any concluded answer may be due to lack of my `pandas` knowledge, just learning..

Much Regards..

Comment: This is not a pandas question this is a JavaScript question. Write a javaScript function that sorts values and add it to the `<th>` of your table: `<th onclick="mySortFunc()">date</th>`

Comment: @Yo_Chris, much regards for giving the comment, i understood.. I'm not Java expert. Is there a library in pandas of python which can be fitted in here.

Comment: None that I am aware of but that does not mean on does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you above datafarame is stored in df. Then use these steps to create a html file and save it somewhere locally.

```
df =  df.to_html(escape=False)

    df=df.replace('<th>','<th class = "th-sm" style="text-align: left">').replace('border="1"','id="example"').replace('class="dataframe"','class="display"')
    msgxx ='''
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]]
    } );
} );</script>
'''
    df = msgxx + df
    df=df.replace('<th>','<th class = "th-sm"')
    filename = 'abc.html'
    f= open(filename, 'w+')
    f.write(df)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Niraj Sir .